# Store true/false in Integer using the bits

Tags: java, integer, boolean, long-integer, bit

**Situation**

What I'm trying to achieve is to store true/false represented as a bit in a Integer/Long. The problem is that I'm unable to solve if a certain bit is 1 or 0.

**Code**

```
public class Test
{
    private static long unlocked = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        setUnlocked(1);
        setUnlocked(2);
        setUnlocked(3);
        System.out.println(isUnlocked(2);
    }

    public static void setUnlocked(int id)
    {
        unlocked += Math.pow(2, id);
    }

    public static boolean isUnlocked(int id)
    {
        // ???
        return false;
    }

}
```

As in the test case above, it will result in the following bits sequence: 1110 = 14.

**Edit**

Second Question:

```
    public static void setUnlocked(int id)
    {
        unlocked |= 1 << id;
    }
```

To

```
    public static void setUnlocked(int id, boolean set)
    {

    }
```

That will give the option to set the bit to 0 or 1 at the given location.

But how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do it easily using masking, but a bitset would be a better idea.    This nano-optimization will provide no value and will make your code unreadable.

Comment: What happens if you set the same id twice?

Comment: I'm posting my answer as a comment: another alternative is to use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Comment: @ScottHunter maybe it's better to have the fuction to setUnlocked(int id, boolean set), but orginal it should set it to 1

Comment: @user2803086: Apparently you haven't actually tried it; my point was that it *won't* be 1.  Fortunately, the answers below address this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bitwise operators :

```
public static void setUnlocked(int id)
{
    unlocked |= 1L<<id; // set the id'th bit
}

public static boolean isUnlocked(int id)
{
    return (unlocked & (1L<<id)) != 0; // get the id'th bit
}
```

`1<<id` is the fastest way to compute 2^id.

bitwise OR (|) lets you set a bit in the int.

bitwise AND (&) lets you get the value of a bit (by clearing all the other bits and checking if the result is not 0).

EDIT :

```
public static void setUnlocked(int id, boolean set)
{
    if (set) {
        unlocked |= 1L<<id; // set the id'th bit
    } else {
        unlocked &= 0xffffffffffffffffL ^ (1L<<id); // clear the id'th bit
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer and upvoting this since it actually answers the question.

Comment: @Eran "The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) long, boolean" at the isUnlocked() method

Comment: @user2803086 hmm, perhaps you need parentheses. see fix

Comment: @Eran thanks! one more question, How would I change the setUnlocked(int id) to setUnlocked(int id, boolean set) to make it also able to set it to 0 again?

Comment: @user2803086 You could use bitwise AND and XOR - `unlocked &= 0xffffffffffffffffL ^ (1<<id);` - it ANDs the original value of unlocked with a long for which all the bits except the id'th bit are 1, so it clears the id'th bit.

Comment: You should use `!= 0` instead of `> 0`.

Comment: @Bubletan Why? is !=0 more efficient than >0?

Comment: @Eran If you use sign bit it would be negative.

Comment: @Eran One small fix, the 1 should be 1L, since now it's capped to an integer not a Long.

Comment: @user2803086 did you notice the fix in `isUnlocked` that Bubletan suggested? (!=0 instead of >0) I tested it with 63 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible approach is to use a plain simple `Set<Integer>`:

```
static Set<Integer> unlocked = new HashSet<>();

public static void setUnlocked(int id) {
    unlocked.add(id);
}

public static boolean isUnlocked(int id) {
    return unlocked.contains(id);
}
```

This approach does not rely on id's to be in any particular range. For thread safety, synchronize on the `Set` if needed.